# Find and replace in ruby+rails, including tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a list of words that I'm matching against displayed strings.  The matching words in the strings should be placed in their own `<b>` tag.

First, is `gsub` the best way to find+replace in ruby?  I don't need full regex power, just substring matching.

Second, wouldn't rails just escape out any tags I attempt to insert as a string into the displayed content?  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're looking for [`highlight` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-highlight):

```
highlight('You searched for: rails', 'rails')
# => You searched for: <strong class="highlight">rails</strong>
```

See the link for more options.